# How to wake up android device from sleep and play a video

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock, keyguard

I want to wake up the device and play a video. 
Here is my code snippet to wake up and disable key guard.

```
pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
    Context.POWER_SERVICE);
keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock keyguardLock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
        (PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP),
        "TAG");
wakeLock.acquire();
keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
playVideo(getApplicationContext());
wakeLock.release();
```

The video is playing but the device is not waking up.

Any suggestions?

**EDITED**
I have found a working solution and I have posted it as an answer.
If there are better solutions, I would like to learn and know of it.
Thank you.

Comment: "The video is playing but the device is not waking up" ???

Comment: Yes Mr_and_Mrs_D. The screen is off but the video is playing in the background.

Comment: Where is this code snipet ? In a service ?

Comment: I implemented a BroadcastReceiver inside the activity (LoginActivity), which I want the video activity (ScreenSaverActivity) to be called when screen is going to sleep. Inside the ScreenSaverActivity, I had the above code snippet. I think it's a mistake to put wakelock.release together with wakelock.aquire. Then I tried adding these three lines to ScreenSaverActivity, eventually it worked; WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON.
Thank you Mr_and_Mrs_D for your answers and time.

Comment: Welcome :) - please post your comment as an answer for the future generations to benefit from and then delete the comment.

Comment: I will Mr_and_Mrs_D. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some referring and trouble I have found a working solution. 
I implemented a `BroadcastReceiver` inside the activity (`LoginActivity`), which I want the video activity (`ScreenSaverActivity`) to be called when screen is going to sleep. Inside the `onCreate` method of `ScreenSaverActivity`, I had the above code snippet as mentioned in the question. 
 
I think it's a mistake to put `wakelock.release` together with `wakelock.aquire`. Then I tried adding these three lines to `ScreenSaverActivity` and changed the above code snippet as follows, which eventually worked; 
     `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);`
     `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);`
     `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

```
    pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);     

    keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
    keyguardLock    =  keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");

    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    keyguardLock.disableKeyguard(); 

    playVideo();
```

And I put, 
         `keyguardLock.reenableKeyguard();`
     `wakeLock.release();`
after stopping video and before going back to previous (`LoginActivity`) activity. 
Is there any better answer. I would like to learn and know of it.